# How to annotate mark rules in vega lite api with parallel text or legend?

Tags: javascript, vega-lite, vega, vega-lite-api

I have made following visualization:

```js
data = [{"student_name": "student 0", "e": "100.15", "d": "127.81"}, {"student_name": "student 1", "e": "100.30", "d": "189.94"}, {"student_name": "student 2", "e": "100.15", "d": "105.33"}, {"student_name": "student 3", "e": "99.41", "d": "85.36"}, {"student_name": "student 4", "e": "100.00", "d": "203.70"}, {"student_name": "student 5", "e": "100.15", "d": "139.05"}, {"student_name": "student 6", "e": "41.72", "d": "41.72"}, {"student_name": "student 7", "e": "100.30", "d": "260.50"}, {"student_name": "student 8", "e": "92.60", "d": "94.53"}, {"student_name": "student 9", "e": "99.11", "d": "86.39"}, {"student_name": "student 10", "e": "97.49", "d": "92.46"}, {"student_name": "student 11", "e": "98.37", "d": "83.58"}, {"student_name": "student 12", "e": "100.15", "d": "182.40"}, {"student_name": "student 13", "e": "100.15", "d": "99.41"}, {"student_name": "student 14", "e": "86.69", "d": "81.95"}, {"student_name": "student 15", "e": "98.08", "d": "306.51"}, {"student_name": "student 16", "e": "100.15", "d": "86.54"}, {"student_name": "student 17", "e": "100.15", "d": "186.39"}, {"student_name": "student 18", "e": "99.26", "d": "93.64"}, {"student_name": "student 19", "e": "100.15", "d": "102.66"}, {"student_name": "student 20", "e": "95.71", "d": "52.96"}, {"student_name": "student 21", "e": "99.85", "d": "99.41"}, {"student_name": "student 22", "e": "98.96", "d": "100.44"}, {"student_name": "student 23", "e": "100.15", "d": "131.07"}, {"student_name": "student 24", "e": "99.56", "d": "76.92"}, {"student_name": "student 25", "e": "100.15", "d": "213.46"}, {"student_name": "student 26", "e": "100.15", "d": "311.24"}, {"student_name": "student 27", "e": "100.15", "d": "21.89"}, {"student_name": "student 28", "e": "96.60", "d": "6.36"}, {"student_name": "student 29", "e": "53.70", "d": "3.70"}, {"student_name": "student 30", "e": "96.75", "d": "46.60"}, {"student_name": "student 31", "e": "100.15", "d": "100.15"}, {"student_name": "student 32", "e": "100.30", "d": "115.68"}, {"student_name": "student 33", "e": "87.13", "d": "103.85"}, {"student_name": "student 34", "e": "100.15", "d": "104.14"}]

createChart = function (data) {
  max_d = d3.max(data, record => parseFloat(record.d));
  max_e = d3.max(data, record => parseFloat(record.e));
  max_y_scale_value_for_d = d3.max([100, max_d]);
  max_y_scale_value_for_e = d3.max([100, max_e]);

  const mean_plot = vl.markRule().data(data)
    .transform([{ "calculate": "toNumber(datum.d)", "as": "d2" }, { "calculate": "toNumber(datum.e)", "as": "e2" }])
    .encode(
      vl.y().fieldQ('d2').aggregate('mean'),
      vl.color({"value": "black", "legend":{"labelExpr": "mean"}}),
      vl.strokeDash({"value": [4,4]}),
      vl.tooltip([{ 'field': 'd2', 'type': 'quantitative', "aggregate": "mean", "title": "Mean watched till timestamp" }])
    ).width(500).height(250);

  const mean_text = vl.markText().data(data)
    .transform([{ "calculate": "toNumber(datum.d)", "as": "d2" }, { "calculate": "toNumber(datum.e)", "as": "e2" }])
    .encode(
      vl.y().fieldQ('d2').aggregate('mean')
    ).width(500).height(250);

  const top_ten_label = vl.markText()
    .encode(
      vl.x().datum("student 20"),
      vl.y().datum(50),
      vl.text().datum("Top 10%")
    );
  
  const top_ten = vl.markRule()
    .data(data)
    .transform([{ "calculate": "toNumber(datum.d)", "as": "d2" }, { "calculate": "toNumber(datum.e)", "as": "e2" }])
    .encode(
      vl.x().datum("student 1").title("Top 10%"),
      vl.color({"value": "lightseagreen"}),
      vl.strokeDash({"value": [4,4]}),
      vl.tooltip([{ "field": "student_name", "title": "Top 10%" }])
      // vl.tooltip([{ 'field': 'd2', 'type': 'quantitative', "aggregate": "mean", "title": "Mean watched till timestamp" }])
    ).width(500).height(250);

  const bottom_ten = vl.markRule()
    .data(data)
    .transform([{ "calculate": "toNumber(datum.d)", "as": "d2" }, { "calculate": "toNumber(datum.e)", "as": "e2" }])
    .encode(
      vl.x().datum("student 20"),
      vl.color({"value": "red"}),
      vl.strokeDash({"value": [4,4]}),
      vl.tooltip([{ "field": "student_name", "title": "Bottom 10%" }])

      // vl.tooltip([{ 'field': 'd2', 'type': 'quantitative', "aggregate": "mean", "title": "Mean watched till timestamp" }])
    ).width(500).height(250);
  
  const mpg = vl.markLine()
    .data(data)
    .transform([{ "calculate": "toNumber(datum.d)", "as": "d2" }, { "calculate": "toNumber(datum.e)", "as": "e2" }])
    .encode(
      vl.x()
      .fieldN('student_name')
      .title('students')
      .axis({ labels: false, ticks: false })
      .sort('-y'),
      vl.y()
      .fieldQ('d2')
      .scale({ "domain": [0, max_y_scale_value_for_d] })
      .title('D = Total watched / Video duration'),
      vl.tooltip([{ 'field': 'student_name', 'title': 'Sudent Name' }
                  , { 'field': 'd', 'title': 'D' }
                  , { 'field': 'e', 'title': 'E' }])
    ).width(500).height(250); 
  
  const plot = vl.layer(mpg, mpg.markCircle(), mean_plot, top_ten, bottom_ten, mean_text, top_ten_label)

  return plot.toObject();
}

const chart_spec_json = this.createChart(data)
const opt = {
               renderer: "canvas",
               actions: false
            };
vegaEmbed("#stats", chart_spec_json, opt);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/4.13.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vega@5.21.0/build/vega.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vega-lite@5.2.0/build/vega-lite.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.unpkg.com/vega-embed@6.20.8/build/vega-embed.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vega-lite-api@5.0.0/build/vega-lite-api.min.js"></script>
<div id="stats" />
```

It renders as follows (run the above script to see it in action):

[image]

Now, all I want is to show text parallel to those rules. Say, text saying "Top 10% students" aligned parallel to green dashed line, "Mean D" aligned parallel to black dashed line and "Bottom 10% students" aligned parallel to red dashed line.

I have tried to add `matkText()` in the above script to render some text annotating the corresponding `markRule()`. But it does not seem to render. Why is this so? Also can we render legend for the same instead of showing text parallel inside the graph? All examples online demonstrate autogenerating legends like those for [`markPoint`](https://vega.github.io/vega-lite/docs/legend.html) or [`markArea`](https://vega.github.io/vega-lite/examples/interactive_legend.html)

Clearly, I am struggling with the usage of vega lite API and not able to infer how to chain the whole API methods together.

Answer (score 2):

You need to add the `text` property to the `markText`.
Not related to the post but you do not need to add the data on every layer. You can add the data and the transformation only once.

```js
data = [{"student_name": "student 0", "e": "100.15", "d": "127.81"}, {"student_name": "student 1", "e": "100.30", "d": "189.94"}, {"student_name": "student 2", "e": "100.15", "d": "105.33"}, {"student_name": "student 3", "e": "99.41", "d": "85.36"}, {"student_name": "student 4", "e": "100.00", "d": "203.70"}, {"student_name": "student 5", "e": "100.15", "d": "139.05"}, {"student_name": "student 6", "e": "41.72", "d": "41.72"}, {"student_name": "student 7", "e": "100.30", "d": "260.50"}, {"student_name": "student 8", "e": "92.60", "d": "94.53"}, {"student_name": "student 9", "e": "99.11", "d": "86.39"}, {"student_name": "student 10", "e": "97.49", "d": "92.46"}, {"student_name": "student 11", "e": "98.37", "d": "83.58"}, {"student_name": "student 12", "e": "100.15", "d": "182.40"}, {"student_name": "student 13", "e": "100.15", "d": "99.41"}, {"student_name": "student 14", "e": "86.69", "d": "81.95"}, {"student_name": "student 15", "e": "98.08", "d": "306.51"}, {"student_name": "student 16", "e": "100.15", "d": "86.54"}, {"student_name": "student 17", "e": "100.15", "d": "186.39"}, {"student_name": "student 18", "e": "99.26", "d": "93.64"}, {"student_name": "student 19", "e": "100.15", "d": "102.66"}, {"student_name": "student 20", "e": "95.71", "d": "52.96"}, {"student_name": "student 21", "e": "99.85", "d": "99.41"}, {"student_name": "student 22", "e": "98.96", "d": "100.44"}, {"student_name": "student 23", "e": "100.15", "d": "131.07"}, {"student_name": "student 24", "e": "99.56", "d": "76.92"}, {"student_name": "student 25", "e": "100.15", "d": "213.46"}, {"student_name": "student 26", "e": "100.15", "d": "311.24"}, {"student_name": "student 27", "e": "100.15", "d": "21.89"}, {"student_name": "student 28", "e": "96.60", "d": "6.36"}, {"student_name": "student 29", "e": "53.70", "d": "3.70"}, {"student_name": "student 30", "e": "96.75", "d": "46.60"}, {"student_name": "student 31", "e": "100.15", "d": "100.15"}, {"student_name": "student 32", "e": "100.30", "d": "115.68"}, {"student_name": "student 33", "e": "87.13", "d": "103.85"}, {"student_name": "student 34", "e": "100.15", "d": "104.14"}]

createChart = function (data) {
  max_d = d3.max(data, record => parseFloat(record.d));
  max_e = d3.max(data, record => parseFloat(record.e));
  max_y_scale_value_for_d = d3.max([100, max_d]);
  max_y_scale_value_for_e = d3.max([100, max_e]);

  const mean_plot = vl.markRule().data(data)
.transform([{ "calculate": "toNumber(datum.d)", "as": "d2" }, { "calculate": "toNumber(datum.e)", "as": "e2" }])
.encode(
  vl.y().fieldQ('d2').aggregate('mean'),
  vl.color({"value": "black", "legend":{"labelExpr": "mean"}}),
  vl.strokeDash({"value": [4,4]}),
  vl.tooltip([{ 'field': 'd2', 'type': 'quantitative', "aggregate": "mean", "title": "Mean watched till timestamp" }])
).width(500).height(250);

  const mean_text = vl.markText({text:"Mean", dy:-10 })
.encode(
  vl.y().fieldQ('d2').aggregate('mean')
).width(500).height(250);

  const top_ten_label = vl.markText({text:"Top 10%", dy:-10, angle:-90 })
.encode(
  vl.x().datum("student 1")
);
  
  const top_ten = vl.markRule()
.data(data)
.transform([{ "calculate": "toNumber(datum.d)", "as": "d2" }, { "calculate": "toNumber(datum.e)", "as": "e2" }])
.encode(
  vl.x().datum("student 1").title("Top 10%"),
  vl.color({"value": "lightseagreen"}),
  vl.strokeDash({"value": [4,4]}),
  vl.tooltip([{ "field": "student_name", "title": "Top 10%" }])
  // vl.tooltip([{ 'field': 'd2', 'type': 'quantitative', "aggregate": "mean", "title": "Mean watched till timestamp" }])
).width(500).height(250);
  
   const bottom_ten_label = vl.markText({text:"Botton 10%", dy:-10, angle:-90 })
.encode(
  vl.x().datum("student 20")
);

  const bottom_ten = vl.markRule()
.data(data)
.transform([{ "calculate": "toNumber(datum.d)", "as": "d2" }, { "calculate": "toNumber(datum.e)", "as": "e2" }])
.encode(
  vl.x().datum("student 20"),
  vl.color({"value": "red"}),
  vl.strokeDash({"value": [4,4]}),
  vl.tooltip([{ "field": "student_name", "title": "Bottom 10%" }])

  // vl.tooltip([{ 'field': 'd2', 'type': 'quantitative', "aggregate": "mean", "title": "Mean watched till timestamp" }])
).width(500).height(250);
  
  const mpg = vl.markLine()
.data(data)
.transform([{ "calculate": "toNumber(datum.d)", "as": "d2" }, { "calculate": "toNumber(datum.e)", "as": "e2" }])
.encode(
  vl.x()
  .fieldN('student_name')
  .title('students')
  .axis({ labels: false, ticks: false })
  .sort('-y'),
  vl.y()
  .fieldQ('d2')
  .scale({ "domain": [0, max_y_scale_value_for_d] })
  .title('D = Total watched / Video duration'),
  vl.tooltip([{ 'field': 'student_name', 'title': 'Sudent Name' }
              , { 'field': 'd', 'title': 'D' }
              , { 'field': 'e', 'title': 'E' }])
).width(500).height(250); 
  
  const plot = vl.data(data)
.transform([{ "calculate": "toNumber(datum.d)", "as": "d2" }, { "calculate": "toNumber(datum.e)", "as": "e2" }])
  .layer(mpg, mpg.markCircle(), mean_plot, top_ten, bottom_ten, mean_text, top_ten_label, bottom_ten_label)

  return plot.toObject();
}

const chart_spec_json = this.createChart(data)
const opt = {
           renderer: "canvas",
           actions: false
        };
vegaEmbed("#stats", chart_spec_json, opt);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/4.13.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vega@5.21.0/build/vega.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vega-lite@5.2.0/build/vega-lite.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.unpkg.com/vega-embed@6.20.8/build/vega-embed.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vega-lite-api@5.0.0/build/vega-lite-api.min.js"></script>
<div id="stats" />
```